# what is the most popular mmorpg game that has an out-of-game api?

Tags: mmo

World of Warcraft is off the table, because of the "WOW Glider Lawsuit" of 2008. Also see: Where is Blizzards official World of Warcraft API? Eve Online has an API

But, what is the MOST popular (in terms of usership) MMO Game that does allow programmers to develop out-of-game things (like an Android app).

Comment: Why is this tagged almost completely with mobile tags? Are you wanting a specifically mobile API?

Comment: More like an API to be used by a mobile device. Does it matter what kind of client uses the API?

Comment: Really any API. My goal is to create real-world-meets-virtual world apps, so anything to help this goal is welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WoW does have an external API with the [Armory](http://cn.wowarmory.com/index.xml). It is read only through. Unless you access the pages with a bad browsers, it returns a clear xml structure. According to various blue forums posts, automatic querying of those pages is okay, unless too many requests are sent.

The Glider Lawsuit was about a bot that linked to the original game client in memory. It is pretty obvious that bots are bad for business because a) players spent less time paying while leveling up and b) other players get frustrated and may leave.

Comment: I've confirmed the existence of the XML file. Very excellent answer!! http://www.weekendcode.com/2010/01/fetch-wow-armory-xml-data-using-php/

Comment: This could have been a good answer, but then you added personal unrequested opinions about what's good and what's bad...

Comment: @Lohoris, i am sorry that you feel that way. Perhaps it helps that even the vendor agrees: [Microsoft launches IE6 countdown site](http://www.techspot.com/news/42692-microsoft-launches-ie6-countdown-website.html)

Comment: @HendrikBrummermann Oh, no, sorry, I don't really care about who agrees with that: point is, it's still an opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Everquest had an instant messaging protocol that allowed communication with in-game players from outside the game. I am unsure if the protocol was well documented or supported by any third party clients.

Comment: Both Champions Online and Star Trek Online support XMPP for chat from out of game. Not sure I would call that an API though.

Comment: Yeah chat is not really an api. its more of a meta-api ;)

Answer (score 2):

EVE Online's Web API is read-only.
It's only to monitor character skils/inventory assets/assets and states of various in-game structures,etc
There are ways to get actual control of EVE(control your ship,actually manage said in-game structures,etc) but they  are against EULA and basically works like WoW Glider